# i have a serious problem to set a background image to fit all the screen

Tags: html, css, background

i want to set a background image to fit all the screen, it works very well on winows but when i open the same page on mobile, i tried android on google chrom, i feel that the image zoom in and out, specially a margin in the bottom of the page has been created, i dont know from where it comes from,

this problem shows when i use

```
background-attachment: fixed;
```

when i remeve it everything is as expected, however the image does'nt looksas i want

```
                background: url('image url');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: fixed;
```

any help please  !!!

i want to set a background image on my whole body tag, without this margin at the bottom of the page

Answer (score 0):

you can try using the shorthand for background:

```
background: url('image url') no-repeat center center fixed;

background-size: cover;
```

Here's an article that uses other methods:
https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/